# Resources where one can find open problems in Analytic Number Theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, open-problems, online-resources

**Edit: I have asked this question separately because I am in need of some resources  which focus on analytic number theory only.So, this question is not a duplicate of:[Resources where I can find open problems in number theory along with their level of difficulty](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421151/resources-where-i-can-find-open-problems-in-number-theory-along-with-their-level) as I am in looking for websites/books/blogs in Analytic Number Theory only. I don't have much knowledge of other branches of number theory.**

I have completed my master's in mathematics a couple of years ago from a good university of my country but due to very strong personal and professional reasons I couldn't get admitted to grad school despite having a good academic background.

> I have a really good background in analytic number theory. I have studied 1 course in Sieve Theory, 2 courses which were based on 2 volumes of Apostol's Number Theory books. I will start a course in Automorphic Forms soon. I don't have guidance of any professor right now and I want to try working on an open problem in Analytic Number Theory.

Can you please let me know of resources( websites/ blogs/books) where I can find open problems in analytic number theory to work on? Since, I don't have a guidence of a prof. due to various reasons, these resources will really help me.

Thank you!

Comment: it would probably be best to get in contact with some professor/postdoc somewhere. In the meantime, you could just look at recent arxiv papers in NT and try to improve some of the results you like :)

Comment: Didn't you already ask that question? [Resources where I can find open problems in number theory along with their level of difficulty](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421151/resources-where-i-can-find-open-problems-in-number-theory-along-with-their-level)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Here, I am interested in problems related to analytic number theory only. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: When I was a student, a nice open problem in analytic number theory was to find the optimal constant in the large sieve inequality ($1/\delta+N-1$; if you do not know what this means, look at a book explaining the large sieve). It now has several proofs, but without reading them you can try your hand at that problem.

Comment: @HenriCohen Thanks!

Comment: Try reading "Analytic Number Theory" by Iwaniec and Kowalski; littered throughout are open questions.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular subfield of ANT that you're interested/specialized in? e.g. sieve theory, $L$-functions, additive problems/circle method, diophantine approximation, etc.?

Comment: @JoshuaStucky I have good background in all of these :Sieve Theory, L-functions, Diophantine approximation, addtive problems.